# create a "by" loop with two variables in R

Tags: r, sorting, loops

I have a data set of animal weights which I want to sort by two factors owner and animal type, if I were going to sort by 1 factor then I would use the "by" function however with two factors I don't know what to do apart from some sort of messy "for" loop (and that isn't working out to well either).

The code below generates an example data set of the type I am trying to sort.

```
owner <-c("Fred", "Mary", "James", "Ingrid", "Schubert", "Alice") #owner names
animal <-c("Cow", "Giant sheep", "Deer", "Giga chicken") #Animal types
data <- data.frame(owner= sample(owner, 1000, replace= TRUE), animal=sample(animal, 1000, replace= TRUE), weight=rnorm(1000,mean=250, sd=50)) #data set
owner.weight <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(owner), ncol=(length(animal)+1))) #set up data frame to store the animal weights
colnames(owner.weight) <-c("owner", animal) #rename columns
owner.weight[,1]<-owner #input in owner names
```

What I want to end up with is a dataframe or matrix that has the column and row variables of the below two way table but with weight sums not animal counts. That way I can see how much weight of each animal each owner has as well as the totals and the ratios.

```
table(data$owner,data$animal)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> xtabs(weight ~., data)
          animal
owner            Cow      Deer Giant sheep Giga chicken
  Alice     8753.989  9397.552    9448.641    11968.743
  Fred     12085.692 12062.136   11934.803     9199.231
  Ingrid   10242.862  8614.974    8668.428    13986.118
  James     8842.253 10450.657   13615.702    10580.488
  Mary      9582.275 15187.274    9005.665    12668.783
  Schubert  7155.185  9440.239   12112.422     7030.887
```

Comment: Thanks it is really nice to have such simple code! when I turn the result into a dataframe it comes in three variable form, which is good for analysis but more difficult to display the results. I used dcast to create a dataframe in the same format as xtabs output. Is this s good option or is there a more direct way?

Comment: Try `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(weight ~., data))` .  Note that data frames do not have dimension names so dimension names `animal` and `owner` are lost.